# in Gatsby / React, when navigating to a page can't scroll it, until reload (on mobile)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, jsx, gatsby

I am currently working on my portfolio site with GatsbyJs however I've come to a quick and abrupt stop as I've got an extremely bizarre error.

So, when I navigate from my portfolio page to my project page through clicking a project on the portfolio page, I cannot scroll the content, there's no errors, nothing CSS wise from what I've looked into that's stopping the scroll.

However, if I reload that page once I get to it, I can then scroll? What could it be?

The current version of the site is here:

[www.12studio.agency](https://www.12studio.agency)

I've disabled components to make sure either nothing is being carried over or affecting the page but it happens regardless of whether components or CSS is turned off. It literally will not scroll on navigation to the page.

Comment: your site is not working

Comment: Yes, im aware of that hence my question above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey everyone so I found out the crazy issue!!!!!!!

It was not related to Gatsby, React or CSS.

This was an issue with the project page previous.

Basically, the project page used a slider (Slick-React) and two settings were colliding with each other.

The settings that collided and broke the next page were as follows:

`verticalSwiping: false,
swipeToSlide: true,`

I changed this after messing around for a good hour to:

`verticalSwiping: false,
swipeToSlide: false,`

This fixed my issue. I hope this helps anybody else!